# JS dynamically created area with buttons is missing when to-do task is edited (and not always)

Tags: javascript

I wanted to create my own To-do list app and I have a problem when I edit a task the area with three buttons (accept, edit and cancel btns) sometimes goes missing.
I'm trying to figure out what's happening with it in the dev tools and it looks like when there are e.g. two tasks (two `li` elements) the `div` area with buttons move from one to another and the second `li` has two `divs` and the first `li` (edited one) it left with no buttons at all.

Here's my code, please excuse any weird things you may find there (I'm not really experienced).

```js
const inputField = document.querySelector('.todo__input')
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.todo__btn')
const ulList = document.querySelector('.todo__list')
const infoParagraph = document.querySelector('.todo__info-paragraph')
const popupDiv = document.querySelector('.pop-up')
const popupAcceptBtn = document.querySelector('.edit-accept')
const popupCancelBtn = document.querySelector('.edit-cancel')
const popupInput = document.querySelector('.edit__input')
const popupInfo = document.querySelector('.edit__info')

let liItem
let acceptButton
let editButton
let cancelButton
let editedTodoTask

let editBtnToBeDisabled

const createLiSpace = () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.classList.add('todo__list-buttons')
  liItem.append(div)

  acceptButton = document.createElement('button')
  acceptButton.classList.add('todo__list-btn')
  acceptButton.classList.add('todo__list-btn--accept')
  acceptButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>'

  editButton = document.createElement('button')
  editButton.classList.add('todo__list-btn')
  editButton.classList.add('todo__list-btn--edit')
  editButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i>'

  cancelButton = document.createElement('button')
  cancelButton.classList.add('todo__list-btn')
  cancelButton.classList.add('todo__list-btn--cancel')
  cancelButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>'

  div.append(acceptButton, editButton, cancelButton)

  acceptButton.addEventListener('click', completeTask)
  editButton.addEventListener('click', showPopup)
  cancelButton.addEventListener('click', deleteTask)
}

const addTask = () => {
  if (inputField.value !== '') {
    liItem = document.createElement('li')
    liItem.classList.add('todo__list-item')
    liItem.textContent = inputField.value
    createLiSpace()
    ulList.appendChild(liItem)

    inputField.value = ''
    infoParagraph.textContent = ''
  } else if (inputField.value == '') {
    infoParagraph.style.color = 'rgb(206, 99, 28)'
    infoParagraph.textContent = 'Please type in your task first!'
  }
}

const showPopup = e => {
  editedTodoTask = e.target.closest('li')
  popupDiv.style.visibility = 'visible'
  popupInfo.textContent = ''
  popupInput.value = editedTodoTask.firstChild.textContent
}

const changeTodoTask = () => {
  if (popupInput.value !== '') {
    editedTodoTask.textContent = popupInput.value
    createLiSpace()
    closePopup()
    popupInput.value = ''
  } else {
    popupInfo.textContent = 'Please type in some text here...'
  }
}

const enterAddTask = (e) => {
  if (e.key == "Enter") {
    addTask()
  }
}

const completeTask = e => {
  editedTodoTask = e.target.closest('li')
  editedTodoTask.classList.toggle('crossline')
}

const closePopup = () => {
  popupDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden'
}

const deleteTask = e => {
  ulList.removeChild(e.target.closest('li'))
}

popupAcceptBtn.addEventListener('click', changeTodoTask)
popupCancelBtn.addEventListener('click', closePopup)
addBtn.addEventListener('click', addTask)
inputField.addEventListener('keyup', enterAddTask)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="todo-top-section">
    <h1 class="todo__header">My to-do list</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type your task here..." class="todo__input">
    <button class="todo__btn"><img class="todo__blob" src="/src/img/blobanimation.svg" alt="">add</button>
  </div>
  <div class="todo-bottom-section">
    <h2 class="todo__heading">Task list:</h2>
    <p class="todo__info-paragraph">No tasks here yet</p>
    <ul class="todo__list">
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="pop-up">
    <h3 class="edit__header">Want to change anything in here?</h3>
    <p class="edit__info"></p>
    <div class="edit-container">
      <input type="text" class="edit__input" placeholder="Type in your change...">
      <div class="todo__list-buttons">
        <button class="todo__list-btn todo__list-btn--accept edit-accept">Accept <i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></button>
        <button class="todo__list-btn todo__list-btn--cancel edit-cancel">Cancel <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Could you please check and specify what is causing that trouble?

You can find my code here too: https://codepen.io/re_aleksandra/pen/PoebEPv

Thank you!

Comment: Protip: You can add more than one class name at a time:  `acceptButton.classList.add('todo__list-btn', 'todo__list-btn--accept')`

Comment: the problem is when you do `editedTodoTask.textContent = popupInput.value` in the `changeTodoTask` function. It overrides its content that is made both of the text you are meant to change AND the buttons. It shows up when you have two tasks created and you try to edit the first one for example. To make it better you could have an element dedicated to the text and change its content only. And I suggest to drop that `createLiSpace` that's just redundant and needed to overcome that lack of better strategy. You just need to change a text content not recreate the whole thing everytime